# Disable Asset logging in Rails 4 + unicorn + foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, unicorn, sprockets, foreman

in Rails 4 + thin, quiet_assets gem worked nicely.

once I added unicorn and ran it with foreman, assets have become noisy again.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay with my answer.  Check to see if my solution below works for you.  I tried to mimic your setup as best I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this under:

- **Ruby** 2.1.0
- **Ruby on Rails** 4.0.2
- **Unicorn** 4.8.2
- **Heroku** `foreman` 0.60.0

In **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
```

When running `foreman start`, you're correct that assets are noisy in the terminal.

However, assets will be suppressed by `tail`ing the development log:

```
$ tail -f log/development.log
```

Comment: is that a recommended practice - to tail the development log?

Comment: this indeed works, guess thats the only way to solve this at the moment

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing in the output is Unicorn logging to STDOUT when it receives and dispatches requests.

You can simply pipe both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null with the following modification, cleaning up the Foreman output to just show the Rails log output:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 > /dev/null 2>&1
rails: tail -f log/development.log
```

This allows you to start your applications with a `foreman start` and have the appropriate logs automatically displayed without clutter.

Comment: GOD bless you! Nice solution! Does this interfere with Heroku's deployment?

Comment: It shouldn't as none of the processes are actually changed.

Comment: But you then lose all web logging, not just assets.